# Rapidshare URL not matching correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to make sure that a Rapidshare URL is valid when a user submits it through my form.

This is the regex that I've come up with so far:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+
```

A rapidshare link looks like this:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/168501977/some_random-file.zip
```

My pattern matches, but not entirely correctly. For example, if we use this input:

```
http://rapidshare.com/files/168501977/some_random-file.zip£%^$
```

It will still match using the PHP function `preg_match()`, and let it go through, even though there are illegal symbols on the end of the URL. I want the pattern to match the entire input, and not just a random length that matches.

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Don't you need to escape the `/`? So `[0-9]+/` would become `[0-9]+\/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to anchor the regex pattern.  Use `^` to anchor the beginning and `$` to anchor the end.  So the pattern becomes:

```
^http://rapidshare.com/files/[0-9]+/[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+$
```

This prevents a partial match of the string like the example is generating.

Answer (score 0):

Validate the start and the end of your string using `^` and `$`. Example:
`^ht{2}p:\/{2}rapidshare\.com\/files\/\d+\/[\.a-zA-Z_-]+$`